# Trying to understand scipy.stats.norm

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, binning

I'm producing a histogram with an overlaid normal distribution, using `scipy.stats.norm`.

This MWE

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

length = 1000
np.random.seed(100)

dictOne = {
           "A": np.random.randn(length),
           "B": np.random.randn(length),
           "C": np.random.randn(length)}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dictOne)

column = 'B'
df = df2[df2[column] > -999]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h, edges, _ = ax.hist(df[column], alpha = 0.5, density = True, bins = 50)
param = stats.norm.fit(df2[column].dropna())   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
x = np.linspace(*df2[column].agg([min, max]), 1000) # x-values

#pdf_fitted = (x, stats.norm.pdf(df2[column], *param))
binwidth = np.diff(edges).mean()
ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, *param)*h.sum()*binwidth, color = 'r')
```

produces
[image]
but when I apply basically the same code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h, edges, _ = ax.hist(df['delta z'], alpha = 0.5, density = True, bins = 50)

param = stats.norm.fit(df['delta z'].dropna())   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
#pdf_fitted = stats.norm.pdf(df['delta z'], *param)
x = np.linspace(*df['delta z'].agg([min, max]), 1000) # x-values
binwidth = np.diff(edges).mean()
ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, *param)*h.sum()*binwidth, color = 'r')

plt.grid(which = 'both')
plt.title(r'$\Delta z$ distribution for %s against %s'%(graph_title, xname), fontsize = 25)
plt.xlabel(r'$\Delta z = z_{spec} - z_{photo}$', fontsize = 25)
plt.ylabel('Number', fontsize = 25)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 25)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)
xmin, xmax = min(df['delta z']), max(df['delta z'])
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.annotate(
r'''$\mu_{\Delta z}$ = %.3f
$\sigma_{\Delta z}$ = %.3f'''%(param[0], param[1]),
         fontsize = 25, color = 'r', xy=(0.85, 0.85), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

to my actual data (which is in a large text file), I get a fit like this:

[image]

The data is in a large text file, so I can't include it here. But my question is, the fit in the toy example is pretty good to the numbers, but with the real data, I would have expected the red curve to fit closer to the histogram. Is there anything I can do to improve the fit, maybe bin size or something? I don't know enough about `scipy.stats` to know how to make it a better fit.

Comment: The discrepancy basically tells you that your data is far from being normally distributed. You can of course try to find a better model than a gaussian to fit your data. That is to say, a fit only makes sense if you have reason to belief that your data obeys to the model you are fitting.

Comment: If you would like to try fitting all of scipy's continuous distributions to your data to find a candidate distribution, I have an online open source statistical distribution fitter at http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/ that does this. Paste in your data and hit the Submit button.

Comment: as mentioned your data is not normally distributed have a look at [stats.kurtosis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html) and [scipy.skew](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html) to give you more information about the shape of your distribution